# Why doesn't onOpen execute. Fails without error message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My onOpen is failing without showing the reason why.  I haven't touched it for months.  It was working up until yesterday.  Any ideas what could be causing it?  And how to fix?

I've also notices I can not save changes to app script.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test","showTest");
  menu.addItem("Run Test","test");
  menu.addItem("Show Sidebar","showSidebar");
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Execution log

[image]

Comment: I know how knowlegeable you're on GAS. I've learned so much from you, so my first thoughts would be shallower than your attemps to solve it, but have the functions been run independently? Is there any library being used that could be yielding the error? Does any of the function need more permission, such as trying access another file, what this trigger doesn't do...?

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand the detailed reason for your current error, for example, when you do the following tests, what result will you obtain? 1. Copy your Spreadsheet and test it again. 2. Create a new Spreadsheet and copy your script to the script editor and test it again. From `I've also notices I can not save changes to app script.`, I'm worried that your Spreadsheet and/or Google Apps Script project might not be able to be used although I'm not sure the reason for it.

Comment: Onit, thanks for your reply. The spreadsheet was simply for testing various functions. I decided to backup all the functions to a text file and then nuke it.  Somehow it got corrupted. Probably from way too much testing.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for such failure is that Simple Triggers cannot be used for processes that require authorization. So, just check for any changes in your global variables that may have caused this.
If yes, then remove the global variables that require authorization. It doesn't matter if you have already provided the consent but simple triggers simply don't work if there are global variables which are authorization dependent.

If you don't want to remove those, then the solution is to not use the default onOpen function provided by AppsScript and instead create a separate function in which you define the same functionality.

Then set the trigger for that function with event source as spreadsheet and eventType as onOpen. It would work exactly as if you were using onOpen function directly.

[image]

Comment: I typically don't use global variables.  Rarely find a need for them.

Comment: Not sure if you have imported a library which has a global variable. Or it may be happening due to some other reason which I am not aware of. In any case, you can still try the solution of creating a separate function and setting the On open trigger. It should solve the issue.

Comment: No not that either.  No libraries.  Too late, I tookTanaike's advise and nuked it and started with a new file.